# pglogical: list Schema/table part of the replication sets?

Tags: postgresql, pg-logical

Is there a way to list all the Schemas which have been added to the replication_set?

```
# SELECT * FROM pglogical.replication_set;
   set_id   | set_nodeid |       set_name       | replicate_insert | replicate_update | replicate_delete | replicate_truncate
------------+------------+----------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------
 1921995266 | 1338498914 | default              | t                | t                | t                | t
 4027572585 | 1338498914 | default_insert_only  | t                | f                | f                | t
 3823354649 | 1338498914 | ddl_sql              | t                | f                | f                | f
 1724847149 | 1338498914 | replication_set | t                | t                | t                | t
(4 rows)
# SELECT pglogical.replication_set_add_all_tables('replication_set', ARRAY['public'],true);
replication_set_add_all_tables
--------------------------------
 t
(1 row)

# SELECT pglogical.replication_set_add_all_tables('replication_set', ARRAY['catalog2'],true);
replication_set_add_all_tables
--------------------------------
 t
(1 row)
```

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. Could you please give an example of what you are expecting to achieve? As it stand your question (for me) is unclear. Hit the [edit] link and add some details to your question. Explain what you are trying to achieve and what you think would be valid results. Thanks.

Comment: "list the array" makes no sense to me.

Comment: I mean, How to list the schema's which added into the replication_set. In the above example, I've added two schemas(public, catalog2) into the replication_set. How to list what other schemas have been added to it?

Answer (score 2):

The pglogical table `replication_set_table` should provide the necessary data. It contains the `set_id` and `set_reloid` (schema.table) columns that point to the schemas and tables that belong to a given replication set.